# netty-tcnative-openssl-static-2.0.28.Final-windows-x86_64.jar is dynamiclly linking to openssl

Tags: openssl, netty, static-linking

After building netty-tcnative-openssl-static-2.0.28.Final-windows-x86_64 from sources, using the created jar file results in unresolved dependency errors at runtime:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: AppData\Local\Temp\1\netty_tcnative2630860948705617016.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Perhaps this is caused by the netty_tcnative.dll having dependencies on openssl dlls:

```
dumpbin /dependents openssl-static\target\native-build\target\x64-release\lib\netty_tcnative.dll
Image has the following dependencies:

    libssl-1_1-x64.dll
    libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    WS2_32.dll
```

Any idea why these would not be statically linked into netty_tcnative.dll?

Build was done using Windows 10, x86 x64 Cross Tools Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openssl build copies import libraries to the target directory

```
netty-tcnative\openssl-static\target\ssl\lib,
```

not static libraries. These are the ones picked up by tcnetty_native build.

However, static libraries are also created with the openssl build

```
netty-tcnative\openssl-static\target\openssl-1.1.1d\*_static.lib
```

As a workaround, copying the _static.lib versions into target directory, replacing the non_static versions did help. Note, this also required to include msvcrt.lib as additional dependency. In netty-tcnative\vs2010.vcxproj.static.template:

```
<AdditionalDependencies>mswsock.lib;ws2_32.lib;rpcrt4.lib;shlwapi.lib;psapi.lib;apr-1.lib;msvcrt.lib;@SSL_LIBS@;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```